# Css rules not working in .net site

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, .net

i am doing some basic stuff in Microsoft visual web developer  , my problem is that when i try to apply class rules  and  link style-sheet that rule is never applied but its applying styles from body level  have a look in my very simple  code

**Header.ascx**

```
</asp:Panel> 
<asp:Panel  id="menuPanel" runat="server"  CssClass="menuPanel">
    <a href="Default.aspx">Home</a> |
    <a href="Titles.aspx">Titles</a> |
    <a href="Authors.aspx">Authors</a> |
    <a href="Publishers.aspx">Publishers</a>
</asp:Panel>
```

and css is linked in head section like this

```
<link href="../Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**CSS File**

```
  .menuPanel
{
    border-width: 1px thick;
    border-color: #000000;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

[image: This is my sol. exlorer]

now when i run this  rule is never applied rest of the css with some global  rules like font-family etc is working fine , whats wrong with this  . Please help  me with  it , Pressing F12 says no resources found

Comment: The stylesheet link is rendered in the final html? No errors in the developer console (F12)?

Comment: yes this is added to default.aspx  . that shows error(F12) not found " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"   whats wrong while css is added in my project

Answer (score 1):

your style is in the same folder as the pages, the ../ means go one folder up.

the correct linking in your case should be

```
<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Page.ResolveClientUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
    href='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Style.css") %>' />
```

Comment: `Server` object don't have `ResolveClientUrl` method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525541%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: ResolveClientUrl is a member of the System.Web.UI.Control class check if u have reference to this namespace

Comment: But you have given `Server.ResolveClientUrl` in answer. What is this `Server` then?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: as i mentioned in question its not about missing link , some of the links are wroking  and some are not thats the  issue

Comment: body, table 
{
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
    font-size:.9em;
}
a 
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
}